# What would be the time complexity for nested loops containing exponential?

Tags: c++, math, time-complexity

```
for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
    for (int j = 1; j <= n; j += pow(i, 2))
        //some O(1) operation
```

What would be the time complexity for this snippet?
For each i in the outer loop, I calculate the how many operations the inner loop will perform, and found:

[image: hello]

But I don't know how to do the math...
And what if I change the pow part to pow(i, 3) or higher power?

Any help is appreciated!

edit: sorry, but I figured I was trying to ask

```
for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
    for (int j = 1; j <= n; j *= i)
        //some O(1) operation
```

And by higher power, I mean j *= (i * i) or j *= i * i * i... and so on.

Sorry again for the wrong question...

Comment: @P.W not really, no, not the question.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher: I think the OP's main issue was about the `pow` function which the other post answers. But I did not mark it as duplicate so that the OP could confirm this.

Comment: @P.W sorry for the misunderstanding, but I'm not involving the pow function's complexity, and assume it to be an O(1) operation. Under the assumption, I'm interested in the overall complexity of the nested loops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The complexity is `O(n)` as @paragon showed. Also, sometimes simply counting how many iterations occour will often reveal the complexity:

```
#include <iostream>

unsigned f(unsigned n) {
    unsigned ctr = 0u;

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= n; j += pow(i, 2)) {
            ++ctr;
        }
    }
    return ctr;
}

int main() {
    for (unsigned n = 1u; n < 9u; ++n) {
        unsigned a = std::pow(10, n) * 2;
        unsigned b = std::pow(10, n);
        std::cout << "f(" << a << ") / f(" << b << ") = " << f(a) / static_cast<double>(f(b)) << '\n';
    }
}
```

showing that it clearly approaches a `O(n)` complexity:

```
f(20) / f(10) = 2.09091
f(200) / f(100) = 2.04016
f(2000) / f(1000) = 2.01001
f(20000) / f(10000) = 2.0035
f(200000) / f(100000) = 2.00105
f(2000000) / f(1000000) = 2.00032
f(20000000) / f(10000000) = 2.0001
f(200000000) / f(100000000) = 2.00003
```

> And what if I change the pow part to pow(i, 3) or higher power?

it will stay still be `O(n)`. It makes sense, because the higher the exponent, the larger `j` grows completing its loop even earlier reducing the complexity to the that of the `i` loop (`i <= n` => `O(n)`):

```
[pow = 1]       f(20000000) / f(10000000) = 2.08026
[pow = 2]       f(20000000) / f(10000000) = 2.0001
[pow = 3]       f(20000000) / f(10000000) = 2.00001
[pow = 4]       f(20000000) / f(10000000) = 2
[pow = 5]       f(20000000) / f(10000000) = 2
[pow = 6]       f(20000000) / f(10000000) = 2
[pow = 7]       f(20000000) / f(10000000) = 2
//...
```

---

adding to @paragon's answer, the series is

[image]

where `p` is the exponent. As `x` grows, the fraction shrinks making the sum approach a fixed value (except for small values of `p` I think)

Answer (score 3):

If I am understanding your code correctly, there shouldn't be logarithms involved. The total number of steps should be

```
n + n/2 + n/2^2 + n/3^2 + ...
```

This is a geometric series. It sums to 2n.

EDIT:
As pointed out in the comments, it is not geometric. The correct sum is pi^2/6*n, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem. But still is is O(n).

Comment: Seems more like it, yes (conclusion O(n) then).

Comment: It is **not** a geometric series – the denominators would be `2^1, 2^2, 2^3, ...` if it were; but the series still converges to a constant (which is less than 2) – see the *Basel Problem*.